# How to use recursion to find the longest string within multiple lists? (Python)

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new here and fairly new to python and I have a question.  I had a similar question during my midterm a while back and it has bugged me that I cannot seem to figure it out.

The overall idea was that I had to find the longest string in a nested list. So I came up with my own example to try and figure it out but for some reason I just can't. So I was hoping someone could tell me what I did wrong and how I can go about the problem without using the function max but instead with a for loop. This is my own example with my code:

```
typing_test = ['The', ['quick', 'brown'], ['fox', ['jumped'], 'over'], 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

def longest_string (nested_list: 'nested list of strings') -> int:
'''return the longest string within the nested list'''

    maximum_length = 0
    for word in nested_list:
        try:
            if type(word) == str:
                maximum_length >= len(word)
                maximum_length = len(word)
            else:
                (longest_string((word)))
        except:
            print('Error')

    return maximum_length
```

My code returns 3 but the highest should be 6 because of the length of jumped I'm not sure if it's going through each list and checking each strings length. In short I don't think it is replacing/updating the longest string. So if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix my example I would greatly appreciate it. And thank you very much in advance.

Comment: when calling longest_string() recursively you need to save it's return value. so maximum_length = max(longest_string(word),maximum_length)

Comment: You also have an error in your "maximum_length >= len(word)".  Currently it is not set up as a proper conditional, and you are doing max_length greater than or equal to word rather than less then (you have discovered a word bigger that your current max_length). It should be "if maximum_length <= len(word):"  That is why you are getting a return of 3 rather than 4 (which is what you should get with the bug in your recursion for the word 'lazy').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems in your code:

- You need to store the value of the recursive call (`maximum_length = (longest_string((word)))`)
- You need to replace the current max value if the length of the word is greater (not less as in your code). There's also no if in this part of your code.

This is the modified code of your function (with minimal modifications to make it work):

```
def longest_string (nested_list):

    maximum_length = 0
    for word in nested_list:
        try:
            if type(word) == str:
                if maximum_length < len(word):
                    maximum_length = len(word)
            else:
                maximum_length = longest_string((word))
        except:
            print('Error')

    return maximum_length
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I see where my errors were and it makes sense why it wasn't changing and why it was necessary to use  < rather than >. Thank you once again and to the other answers below I was just curious about using a for loop because that is what we use in class but thank you I will remember these different ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use the recursion to figure out the longest string in a nested list.

The recursion should be able to have an end condition. For your question, I would like to put "If the parameter is a str".

Then, suppose the parameter will always be str or list, and we do not consider other boundary conditions, the code will be like:

```
def longest_string(p):
    if type(p) == str:
        return len(p)  # Return the length of the str.

    return max([longest_string(x) for x in p])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List Comprehension:

```
def longest(lst):
    return max([0]+[i for i in lst if isinstance(i,int)]+
               [len(s) for s in lst if isinstance(s,str)]+
               [longest(L) for L in lst if isinstance(L,list)])
```

The [0] is needed for an empty list including at the top level.